# vhdl signal generated faster before it is needed

Tags: buffer, vhdl, fpga

I have a question about VHDL.
I"m driving an RGB LED matrix using an FPGA.
I have two main entities. The DRIVER and the COLLECTOR.
The DRIVER is used to just send the signals to the LED matrix.
The COLLECTOR is used to collect the incoming signals (from an Android device) and split them accordingly before sending these signals to the DIRVER.

The problem is, the signals generated in the COLLECTOR to drive the LED matrix, is generated faster than the Driver can accept it. 
How do you solve a problem at which a signal is generated before it is needed?

Comment: Your code so far could be giving more hints here. To the subject: What about taking one clock signal for both the collector and the driver and only synchronize their signals on a clock edge.

Comment: "generated before it is needed" and "generated faster than the driver can accept it" might be two different things. Do you just need to delay it, or are you generating data faster than you can consume it (i.e. a rate/throughput problem, which would be more serious)?

Comment: You may consider using a [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO), if the incoming data comes in bursts, but the incoming and outgoing bandwidth matches in average over time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not mention if you are running in a clocked process or not. If you are using combinatorial logic (not clocked), then you're at the mercy of routing delays and you're stuck.

I'm going to assume that you are using clocked processes.  In that case, you should try using a shift-register to delay one of your signals by 'n' clock cycles.

```
-- <...usual entity/architecture preamble...>

constant CLOCK_DELAYS : natural := 10;
signal sreg : std_logic_vector(CLOCK_DELAYS - 1 downto 0);

begin -- start of RTL

process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    sreg <= sreg(CLOCK_DELAYS - 2 downto 0) & i_signal;
  end if;
end process;

o_signal <= sreg(CLOCK_DELAYS - 1);
```